# Select 3rd level connection where at least 2 2nd level connections have it as their connection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 2 tables: people and connections. Connections has person_id foreign key and  connection_id foreign key.

What I need is to select a connection of connection of a given person (3rd level connection) where at least 2 2nd level connections have the 3rd level connection as their connection. 1st level connections of the original person should not be included.

I have tried  nested where clauses but was only able to get as far as selecting all 3rd level connections.

My last attempt has an error(and is probably way off):

```
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `id` =
ANY(SELECT `connection_id`, COUNT(*)
FROM `people_connections` WHERE `person_id` = 7)
```

I am using OO PHP so having separate smaller queries is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on SQLFiddle to get the people.id of the third-connections you want.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d32c/4

```
SELECT d.connect_id
FROM people_connections c
INNER JOIN people_connections d ON c.connect_id = d.person_id AND d.connect_id <> c.person_id
WHERE c.person_id = @yourIdHere
GROUP BY d.connect_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

A way without JOINS:

```
SELECT connect_id
FROM people_connections
WHERE person_id <> @yourIdHere AND
  person_id IN (SELECT connect_id 
                    FROM people_connections
                    WHERE person_id = @yourIdHere)
GROUP BY connect_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Any way to do this without joins? I would rather execute a smaller query then loop over it's values or something like this.

Comment: Worked perfectly, add it as an answer please.

Comment: Edited it in, happy to have helped!